# Pivot Kafka KTable results using flatMap

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've got two JSON documents as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "ProductID": 12,
    "ProductName": "Product 1",
    "CountryID": 55,
    "CountryName": "Country 1",
    "Companies": [{
        "CompanyID": 1,
        "CompanyName": "Company 1"
      }, {
        "CompanyID": 2,
        "CompanyName": "Company 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 13,
    "ProductName": "Product 2",
    "CountryID": 55,
    "CountryName": "Country 1",
    "Companies": [{
        "CompanyID": 1,
        "CompanyName": "Company 1"
      }, {
        "CompanyID": 2,
        "CompanyName": "Company 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And this is supposed to be a KTable, not a KStream because some records will be deleted.

Key is `(ProductID, CountryID)`.

I'd like to pivot this data and have `(CompanyID)` as a key together with every `(ProductID, CountryID)` combinations in an array in such manner:

```json
[
  {
    "CompanyID": 1,
    "CompanyName": "Company 1",
    "ProductsCountries": [{
        "ProductID": 12,
        "CountryID": 55
      }, {
        "ProductID": 13,
        "CountryID": 55
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CompanyID": 2,
    "CompanyName": "Company 2",
    "ProductsCountries": [{
        "ProductID": 12,
        "CountryID": 55
      }, {
        "ProductID": 13,
        "CountryID": 55
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And whenever a `(ProductID, CountryID)` combination disappears from my KTable, I'd like to remove it from array where `(CompanyID)` has it.

This seems to be semi-possible using KStream because I could just flatMap it and add new `(ProductID, CountryID)` combinations to my document, however I won't be able to capture deletes.

Is there a way to do it with KTable?